# Getting error that method is not defined

Tags: ios, xib

I have a subview that is linking to a detail subview. See below. This .h is EXACTLY the same in the two header files I am currently using, except for the @interface ***_*** (JohnAdams on one and GeorgeWashington on the other.

```
@interface JohnAdams : UIViewController {

NSString *selectedCountry;
IBOutlet UIButton *bio;
IBOutlet UIButton *wiki; 
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedCountry;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *wiki;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *bio;

-(IBAction)wikiButtonPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)bioButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

However, take a look at the two .m's

```
//George Washington.m
-(IBAction)wikibuttonPressed:(id)sender {
WebView1 *detailvc = [[WebView1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebView1" bundle:nil];
[detailvc setTitle:@"Wikipedia"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailvc animated:YES];
[detailvc release];

 }

-(IBAction)biobuttonPressed:(id)sender {
WebView2 *detailvc2 = [[WebView2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebView2" bundle:nil];
[detailvc2 setTitle:@"The White House"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailvc2 animated:YES];
[detailvc2 release];
}

//JohnAdams.m
-(IBAction)biobuttonPressed:(id)sender {
WebView4 *detailvc4 = [[WebView4 alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebView4" bundle:nil];
[detailvc4 setTitle:@"The White House"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailvc4 animated:YES];
[detailvc4 release];
}


-(IBAction)wikibuttonPressed:(id)sender {
WebView3 *detailvc3 = [[WebView3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebView3" bundle:nil];
[detailvc3 setTitle:@"Wikipedia"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailvc3 animated:YES];
[detailvc3 release];

}
```

In John Adams.m, rather than loading WebView3 and WebView4, it loads WebView1 and WebView2. Additionally, John Adams.m receives a warning that method definition for both -wikiButtonPressed and bioButtonPressed are undefined (but not on GeorgeWashington.m). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So when the JohnAdams bio button is pressed, execution doesn't enter the code in JohnAdams.m? If this is the case, the xib is probably linked to the wrong controller.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the interface builder? 
(Apparently you do because you are declaring IBOutlets)

If so then check the class name of the files owner of JohnAdams.xib.